# How to setup a (new) monetdb db from scratch in python?

Tags: python, monetdb

I'm trying to create a monetdb db with python. The db doesn't exist at the beginning: the code should create it specifying the port, the folder were it will reside & the db name.
All the examples I could fine clearly assume that the db exists already. 
In some way this should be similar to the operations typically managed by the moneddbd deamon. 
How do I setup a (new) monetdb db in python from scratch?

Comment: i'm not aware that anyone's automated the creation of the bat file inside of python.  it has been automated within R, however - to view the R code, run `library(MonetDB.R);monetdb.server.setup` to construct the database and then `?monetdb.server.start` to launch the server.

Comment: I'm fully aware of the R library MonetDB.R, in fact I have an open question on stackoverflow about it (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21779280/csv-load-error-with-monetdb-r/21781080?noredirect=1#comment32980814_21781080).  I was thinking of using python as an alternative...

Comment: i saw ;)  on windows, you just have to write the text of a bat file.  on non-windows, i believe the commands are even easier.  `monetdb.server.setup` should give you everything you need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it is:

```
import monetdb.control

control=control.Control(port=port,passphrase=None)
control.create(database)
control.release(database)
```

Another way (my way):

```
import subprocess

farm_path="/home/me/..."
database_name="test"
subprocess.call("monetdbd create "+farm_path,shell=True,executable="/bin/bash")
subprocess.call("monetdbd start "+farm_path,shell=True,executable="/bin/bash")
subprocess.call("monetdb create "+database_name,shell=True,executable="/bin/bash")
subprocess.call("monetdb release "+database_name,shell=True,executable="/bin/bash")
```

If you want a bit more detailed code, let me know.